# Does java.net.Socket detect client timeouts?

Tags: java, sockets, timeout

I'm using **Scala** with **java.net.Socket** and **java.net.ServerSocket**.

I want to detect when a socket connection with a client is disconnected/timed out.

I've implemented my own detection like this, which works:

```
var break = false
var startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
while(!break){
  if(inputstream.ready()){
    //...parse input
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
  }else if(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime >= 5000){
    break = true
  }
}
socket.close()
```

So my implementation closes the socket when a message hasn't been received from the client for 5000ms.

But I wonder whether there is something in the library that I can use to detect the timeout instead.

**If a client turns off their program or their Internet connection terminates etc**, is there something on the Network Layer, Transport Layer, or otherwise, that somehow my server can know immediately through the library (java.net.Socket)?

Is an Exception thrown immediately or is there some timeout detection feature?

Answer (score 1):

You may try `socket.setSOTimeout(5000)`.
In this case, an exception java.io.InterruptedIOException will be thrown if a read on the input stream takes more than 5 seconds.